# How to avoid repetition in Flutter while using JsonSerialzable

Tags: flutter, dart

I have models that I need to map them to JSON and vice versa. Therefore, I've followed flutter's [JSON and serialization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) guide on how to do so.

I found myself writing the same code base for each model, like so:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'folder_entity.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class FolderEntity {
  final String id;
  final String path;
  bool isSelected;

  FolderEntity({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.path,
    this.isSelected = false,
  });

  factory FolderEntity.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$FolderEntityFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => _$FolderEntityToJson(this);
}
```

I thought about moving `fromMap` and `toMap` to a new abstract class called `Entity`, but I'm unable to do so for two reasons:

1. I can't extend a `factory`, therefore I have write the same pattern for each method.
2. I'm not sure if there's an option to change prefix from `_$FolderEntity` to just `_$Entity`, and if would still be available, will it even work?

Comment: Can you explain first question?

Comment: @NikhilVadoliya I have entities (resource models) in my app. I first fetch them from a database as maps, and then I transform them into entity classes, by providing a factory `Entity.fromMap`. But the problem is, that I cannot extend a factory, so I'm looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

For second question you should be change prefix from `_$FolderEntity` to just `_$Entity`  in  `folder_entity.g.dart` file.

Comment: The question is how to change the prefix, not what I need to do.